# Mocking Http Post Request using Jest in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have an external POST API built using native https.request using Node Js inside Azure Function and everything works fine. Now I am trying to build Unit Test cases and got struck at mocking Request method.

The callback response has 'on' function which needs to be mocked based on value either 'data' or 'end'.

I get this error **TypeError: res.on is not a function**

Below is the Code. Any suggestions !

index.js

```
'use strict';
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = function(context, postData) {
    //Accessing Certificate and Passing along with Request Options for SSL Handshake
    var ca_path = path.join(__dirname, 'my_cert.cer');
    https.globalAgent.options.ca = fs.readFileSync(ca_path).toString()
        .split(/-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n?/)
        // may include an extra empty string at the end
        .filter(function(cert) { return cert !== ''; })
        // effectively split after delimiter by adding it back
        .map(function(cert) { return cert + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n'; });

    let auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(process.env.username + ':' + process.env.pwd).toString('base64');

    let post_option = {
        host: process.env.host,
        path: process.env.path,
        method: 'POST',
        port: process.env.port,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': auth,
            'X-Correlation-ID': JSON.parse(postData).correlationId
        }
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = https.request(post_option, function(res) {
            // accumulate data
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) { //here is the type error
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            // resolve on end
            res.on('end', function() {
                context.log("API status: " + res.statusCode);
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    try {
                        body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                        context.log("API Success: ");
                    } catch (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(body);
                } else if (res.statusCode == 401) {
                    let errJson = {};
                    context.log("API authentication error...");
                    let err = new Error();
                    errJson["errorCode"] = res.statusCode;
                    errJson["errorMessage"] = res.statusMessage;
                    errJson["errorDescription"] = res.statusMessage;
                    err = errJson;
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                    context.log("API error...", body);
                    let err = new Error();

                    if (body.error != null && body.error != undefined) {
                        err = body.error;
                    } else {
                        let errJson = {};
                        errJson["errorCode"] = res.statusCode;
                        errJson["errorMessage"] = res.statusMessage;
                        errJson["errorDescription"] = res.statusMessage;
                        err = errJson;
                    }
                    return reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
        // reject on request error
        req.on('error', function(err) {
            context.log("API Generic error...", err);
            let err = new Error();
            let errJson = {};
            if (err.message && err.message.indexOf("ENOTFOUND") >= 0)
                errJson["errorCode"] = 404;
            else
                errJson["errorCode"] = 500;
            errJson["errorMessage"] = err.message;
            errJson["errorDescription"] = err.message;
            err = errJson;
            reject(err);
        });
        if (postData) {
            req.write(postData);
        }
        req.end();
    });
}
```

index.test.js

```
 var https = require('https');
    jest.mock('https', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('https'), // import and retain the original functionalities
    request: (post_option, cb) => cb('res')({
         on: jest.fn()
    }),
    on: jest.fn(),
    write: jest.fn(),
    end: jest.fn()
}));


 /*
jest.mock('https', () => ({
...jest.requireActual('https'), // import and retain the original functionalities
request: (post_option, cb) => cb('res')({
    on: (data, cb) => cb('data')
}),
on: jest.fn(),
write: jest.fn(),
end: jest.fn()
}));
*/

/*    jest.mock('https', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('https'), // import and retain the original functionalities
      request: (post_option, cb) => cb(jest.fn(() => ({
        on: jest.fn()
      }))),
      on: jest.fn(),
      write: jest.fn(),
      end: jest.fn()
      })); 
*/

/*  jest.mock('https', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('https'), // import and retain the original functionalities
    request: (post_option, cb) => cb({
     on: jest.fn()
    })
    })); 
*/
```

Tried different ways to create mock for 'on' function but not success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 3 hours of experiments, finally I was able to mock 'on' function of 'res'.

**cb should actually set to a function expecting 2 params**

Here is the mock syntax.

```
let apiResponseBody = `{
                         "status": "Dummy Request sent to API"
                       }`;
    
var https = require('https');
jest.mock('https', () => ({
 ...jest.requireActual('https'), // import and retain the original functionalities
 request: (post_option, cb) => cb({
  on: (data, cb) => cb(Buffer.from(apiResponseBody, 'utf8')),
  statusCode: 200,
  statusMessage: 'API Success'
 }),
 on: jest.fn(),
 write: jest.fn(),
 end: jest.fn()
}));
```